# Post form data with extra values to the server

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

How do I post both form data as well as some other values (i.e. `{a:'A',b:'B',c:'C'}`) to the server using jQuery ajax?

Html code:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <p>firstname: <input name="firstname" type="text" value="John" /></p>
    <p>lastname: <input name="lastname" type="text" value="Doe" /></p>
</form>
```

Javascript code:

```
var data={a:'A',b:'B',c:'C'};
$.post('index.php',data); //This seems to work 

var formData=$('#myForm').serializeArray();
$.post('index.php',formData);  //This seems to work 

//Wish to post {a:'A',b:'B',c:'C',firstname:'John',lastname:'Doe'} to the server
//Doesn't work
$.extend( data, formData );
console.log(data);
$.post('index.php',data);
```

Answer (score 1):

guest271314 probably has the best answer, but would like opinions of this answer.

```
var data=$('#myForm').serializeArray();
$.each({a: "A", b: "B", c: "C"},function(n,v){data.push({ name : n, value : v });});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: This seems to be the better choice, because `serializeArray()` method uses the standard W3C [**successful controls**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2), this way you will ensure that disabled form input fields will not be added, you are also including textareas and select fields. Input fields of type submit will not be added. Hidden controls and controls that are not rendered because of style sheet settings may still be added.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.each()` to iterate `input` elements within `form` , set `this.name` property of `input` to `this.value` of `input` at existing `data` object

```js
var data = {
  a: "A",
  b: "B",
  c: "C"
};

$("form input").each(function() {
  data[this.name] = this.value
});

console.log(data);

// $.post("index.php", data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <p>firstname:
    <input name="firstname" type="text" value="John" />
  </p>
  <p>lastname:
    <input name="lastname" type="text" value="Doe" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: So, no `serializeArray()`?  When should `serializeArray()` be used? Why not always do it this way and never use `serializeArray()`?

Comment: @user1032531 `.serializeArray()` creates array containing multiple objects , requirement at Question appear to be single object containing all properties , values

Comment: Either will post the same, no?  I do, however, tend to like your solution more.

Comment: @user1032531 _"Either will post the same, no?"_ Either will post to server , yes . Though data structure different ; `.serializeArray()` returns array of possibly multiple objects : `"[{"name":"firstname","value":"John"},{"name":"lastname","value":"Doe"}]"` , approach at solution above returns single object containing properties of original `data` , name , value of `input` elements within `form` : `{a: "A", b: "B", c: "C", firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe"}`

Answer (score -1):

`serializeArray()` returns set of form elements as an array of names and values. Data will be like in the format

```
[{ name: "name", value: "value" },.....]
```

So you cant use `$.extend()` so you can do something like this

```
var formData=$('#myForm').serialize();

$.each(data,function(i,v){
    formData+='&'+i+'='+v;
});
console.log(data);
$.post('index.php',formData);
```

or

```
var formData=$('#myForm').serializeArray();

$.each(data,function(i,v){
    formData.push({name:i,value:v});
});
console.log(data);
$.post('index.php',formData);
```

or define array same as serialized array

```
var newData = [{name:"a", value:"A"}, {name:"b", value:"B"}];
formData=$.merge(formData,newData);
$.post('index.php',formData);
```

Comment: Guess I could push individually `{a:'A',b:'B',c:'C'}`, but it seems like there should be a better way.  Is there an alternative to `serializeArray()` which doesn't return array name/values?

Answer (score -1):

Use $.merge and transform your object to an array structure,

```
var newData  = [];
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
   newData.push({name:k, value:v});
});
formData=$.merge(formData,newData);
console.log(data);
$.post('index.php',data);
```